# Best way to store large amount of data on device when internet connection is lost

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hi I was really hoping to get some guidance with React Native. I'm currently building an App using expo. It's a two part question.

1. was how to go about storing data when the internet connection is lost.  In Africa, internet connection can be lost at any time.
   Currently, once the user is logged in, I am saving data into state using Context API.  I save my access token on Secure store and some user data on Async storage.  However these dont store large amounts of data.  How reliable and efficient is SQLite and realm and would you recommend any other option?  Realm is not supported on Expo Go however it is seeming to be the best option.

and 2) Supposing I used SQLite or any other option to store data on the phone, how to i go about updating the data on the phone with the newest data on the server once internet connection comes back.  I was thinking to overide the entire data?